# Can Mathematica Export Shapefiles?

Tags: export, geodesy

*Mathematica* is great at importing ESRI shapefiles (.shp).

```
Import["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/usamap.zip", "Graphics"]
```

[image]

But it seems like it's a glaring omission that it can't export them. Does MMA have the ability?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes it can. Now it's not necessarily easy, but all the groundwork is in place to build a function that can export ESRI shapefiles.

(A lot of code follows....) **UPDATE: Available on GitHub as a Wolfram Language Package. See [here](https://github.com/kalew/MMAExportSHP).**

First, a [shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) consists of at least three essential files: 1) the .shp main file, 2) the .shx index file, and 3) the .dbf--a hateful file format that stores the tabular data related to the feature. Sadly, the .dbf file is another one that *Mathematica* can import but not export. The .shp and .shx files change endianness frequently, but are otherwise pretty straight forward.

I found it easier to write functions that first import the data so I could study how it worked. I then reversed that to write the export functions. I can include those functions if there is a desire. Only the `Export` functions are shown here.

Now to the functions:

Here's a function to write the .shp and .shx files simultaneously:

```
writeshp[geometry_, filepath_] := 
 Module[{str = OpenWrite[filepath, BinaryFormat -> True], 
   shx = OpenWrite[StringReplace[filepath, ".shp" -> ".shx"], 
     BinaryFormat -> True], shapetype, bounds, recordnumber = 0},
  BinaryWrite[str, {9994, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, filelength[geometry]}, 
   "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  shapetype = 
   Pick[{1, 3, 5}, {Point, Line, Polygon}, 
     Commonest[geometry[[All, 0]]][[1]]][[1]];
  BinaryWrite[str, {1000, shapetype}, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  bounds = 
   If[shapetype == 1, MinMax /@ geometry[[All, 1]], 
    MinMax /@ Transpose[Join @@ (geometry[[All, 1]])]];
  BinaryWrite[
   str, {bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
    bounds[[2, 2]], 0., 0., 0., 0.}, "Real64", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  BinaryWrite[shx, {9994, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (100 + 8*Length@geometry)/2},
    "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[shx, {1000, shapetype}, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  BinaryWrite[
   shx, {bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
    bounds[[2, 2]], 0., 0., 0., 0.}, "Real64", ByteOrdering -> -1];
  Which[
   shapetype == 1,
   Do[writepoint[str, shx, record, recordnumber++], {record, 
     geometry}],
   shapetype == 3,
   Do[writepolyline[str, shx, record, recordnumber++], {record, 
     geometry}],
   shapetype == 5,
   Do[writepolygon[str, shx, record, recordnumber++], {record, 
     geometry}]
   ];
  Close[str];
  Close[shx];
  ]
```

It has four helper functions:

```
writepolyline[stream_, shxstream_, linerecord_, recordnumber_] := 
 Module[{numpart = Depth@linerecord[[1]] - 2, numpoints, bounds},
  If[numpart > 1, numpoints = Total[Length /@ linerecord[[1]]]; 
   bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose[Join @@ (linerecord[[1]])], 
   numpoints = Length@linerecord[[1]]; 
   bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose[linerecord[[1]]]];
  BinaryWrite[
   shxstream, {StreamPosition[stream]/2, 
    22 + 2*numpart + 8*numpoints}, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[stream, {recordnumber, 22 + 2*numpart + 8*numpoints}, 
   "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[
   stream, {3, bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
    bounds[[2, 2]], numpart, numpoints, 
    Sequence @@ Range[0, numpart - 1], 
    Sequence @@ (Flatten@linerecord[[1]])}, {"Integer32", "Real64", 
    "Real64", "Real64", "Real64", "Integer32", "Integer32", 
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Integer32", numpart], 
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Real64", numpoints*2]}, 
   ByteOrdering -> -1]
  ]

writepoint[stream_, shxstream_, pointrecord_, recordnumber_] := 
 Module[{numpart = Depth@pointrecord[[1]] - 2, numpoints, bounds},
  BinaryWrite[shxstream, {StreamPosition[stream]/2, 10}, "Integer32", 
   ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[stream, {recordnumber, 10}, "Integer32", 
   ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[
   stream, {1, Sequence @@ (Flatten@pointrecord[[1]])}, {"Integer32", 
    "Real64", "Real64"}, ByteOrdering -> -1]
  ]

writepolygon[stream_, shxstream_, polyrecord_, recordnumber_] := 
 Module[{numpart = Depth@polyrecord[[1]] - 2, numpoints, bounds},
  If[numpart > 1, numpoints = Total[Length /@ polyrecord[[1]]]; 
   bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose[Join @@ (polyrecord[[1]])], 
   numpoints = Length@polyrecord[[1]]; 
   bounds = MinMax /@ Transpose[polyrecord[[1]]]];
  BinaryWrite[
   shxstream, {StreamPosition[stream]/2, 
    22 + 2*numpart + 8*numpoints}, "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[stream, {recordnumber, 22 + 2*numpart + 8*numpoints}, 
   "Integer32", ByteOrdering -> 1];
  BinaryWrite[
   stream, {5, bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
    bounds[[2, 2]], numpart, numpoints, 
    Sequence @@ Range[0, numpart - 1], 
    Sequence @@ (Flatten@polyrecord[[1]])}, {"Integer32", "Real64", 
    "Real64", "Real64", "Real64", "Integer32", "Integer32", 
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Integer32", numpart], 
    Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Real64", numpoints*2]}, 
   ByteOrdering -> -1]
  ]

filelength[geometry_] := 
 Module[{shapetype = 
    Pick[{1, 3, 5}, {Point, Line, Polygon}, 
      Commonest[geometry[[All, 0]]][[1]]][[1]], 
   records = Length@geometry[[All, 1]], 
   points = Length@Flatten@geometry[[All, 1]], 
   parts = Total[Depth /@ geometry[[All, 1]] - 2]},
  If[shapetype == 1, 28*records + 100, 
    52*records + 4*parts + 8*points + 100]/2
  ]
```

As mentioned before, the .dbf file also must be written. Here's a function to write the .dbf for 3 data types (strings, integers, and floats but it can easily be extended to others if needed):

```
writedbf[assoc_, filepath_] := 
 Module[{str = OpenWrite[filepath, BinaryFormat -> True], 
   vals = Values@assoc, fieldnames = Keys[assoc], fieldtypes, offsets,
    header, subrecords, recods, recordstart, records},
  fieldnames = 
   If[StringLength[#] > 10, StringTake[#, 10], #] & /@ fieldnames;
  fieldtypes = Commonest[Head /@ #][[1]] & /@ vals;
  Do[If[fieldtypes[[i]] == Real, 
    vals[[i]] = realformat[vals[[i]]]], {i, Length@vals}];
  offsets = 
   Table[Switch[fieldtypes[[i]], 
     String, {Max[50, Max[Length /@ vals[[i]]]], 0}, Integer, {16, 0},
      Real, {19, 11}], {i, Length@vals}];
  fieldtypes = 
   Pick[{"C", "N", "F"}, {String, Integer, Real}, #][[1]] & /@ 
    fieldtypes;
  subrecords = 
   Flatten@Table[
     Flatten[{PadRight[ToCharacterCode[fieldnames[[i]]], 11, 0], 
       ToCharacterCode[fieldtypes[[i]]], 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       Sequence @@ offsets[[i]], 0, ConstantArray[0, 13]}], {i, 
      Length@fieldnames}];
  recordstart = 32*(Length@vals + 1) + 1;
  records = 
   Transpose@
    Table[If[fieldtypes[[i]] == "N", PadLeft, PadRight][
      ToCharacterCode[ToString[vals[[i, j]]]], offsets[[i, 1]], 
      32], {i, Length@vals}, {j, Length@vals[[i]]}];
  header = {3, DateList[][[1]] - 1900, DateList[][[2]], 
    DateList[][[3]], Length@vals[[1]], recordstart, 
    Length@Flatten@records[[1]] + 1, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, 17],
     87, 0, 0};
  BinaryWrite[str, 
   header, {Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Byte", 4], "Integer32", 
    "Integer16", "Integer16", Sequence @@ ConstantArray["Byte", 20]}];
  BinaryWrite[str, subrecords, "Byte"];
  BinaryWrite[str, {13}, "Byte"];
  BinaryWrite[str, Flatten[Prepend[#, 32] & /@ (Join @@@ records)], 
   "Byte"];
  BinaryWrite[str, {26}, "Byte"];
  Close[str];
  ]
```

And one helper function to format `Real` numbers:

```
realformat[num_] := 
 ToString@ScientificForm@PaddedForm[num, {12, 11}, 
  NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToExpression[(#3 /. "" -> "0")] < 0, "-", "+"], StringPadLeft[StringReplace[ToString@#3, "-" -> ""], 3,  "0"]}] &)]
SetAttributes[realformat, Listable]
```

And finally a function to wrap it all together:

```
exportshapefile[filepath_, geometry_, assoc_] := Module[{},
  If[! StringMatchQ[filepath, __ ~~ "SHP", IgnoreCase -> True], 
   Abort[]];
  If[Length@First@Values@assoc != Length@geometry, Abort[]];
  writeshp[geometry, filepath];
  writedbf[assoc, StringReplace[filepath, ".shp" -> ".dbf"]];
  filepath
  ]
```

For point features:

```
cities = {Entity["City", {"Houston", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"SanAntonio", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
   Entity["City", {"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}]};
geometry = 
  Point /@ Reverse /@ (LatitudeLongitude[#] & /@ cities // QuantityMagnitude);
data = <|"Name" -> {"Houston", "San Antonio", "Dallas"}, 
  "Population" -> (CityData[#, "Population"] & /@ cities // QuantityMagnitude), 
  "Elevation" -> (CityData[#, "Elevation"] & /@ cities // QuantityMagnitude)|>

exportshapefile["filepath\\lines.shp", geometry, data];
```

Now let's pull it in to ArcMap. Since the .prj file isn't a standard format, we don't write it, but you can use the Define Projection toolbox with ArcGIS to do that. It will create the .prj file for us:

[image]

[image]

We can then just copy the newly created prj file for use in the other examples.

Polylines:

```
geometry = 
  Line /@ Subsets[Reverse /@ (LatitudeLongitude[#] & /@ cities //  QuantityMagnitude), {2}];
distances = (GeoDistance @@@ Map[Reverse, geometry[[All, 1]], {2}] // QuantityMagnitude);
cesnaspeed = 
  WolframAlpha["speed of a cesna in mph", {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}] // QuantityMagnitude;
data = <|"ID" -> {1, 2, 3}, "Distance" -> distances, "CesnaTime" -> distances/cesnaspeed|>

exportshapefile["filepath\\lines.shp", geometry, data];
```

[image]

And lastly, polygons:

```
geometry = {Polygon[Reverse /@ (LatitudeLongitude[#] & /@ cities // QuantityMagnitude)]};
data = <|"Name" -> {"The Triangle!"}|>;

exportshapefile["filepath\\poly.shp", geometry, data];
```

[image]

The ESRI format supports other shape types. And it would be trivial to extend the above functions to handle those, I just didn't have a need at the time. Hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks to @WReach's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14988/import-fortran-unformatted-binary) for providing a lot of the knowledge for binary files.

Comment: Could you make a package out of this and host it somewhere else than SE? (GitHub?)  It looks quite useful.

Comment: @Szabolcs I could.... if I knew how to operate GitHub... which I don't--embarrassingly.

Comment: @Szabolcs Okay, I added this to GitHub. Can you check and make sure I did it correctly.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html) to "teach" `Export[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Interesting. Never knew you could do that. I'll add this later... Right now, if I think anymore about shapefiles, I may stroke out.

Comment: Very nice, I can find a use for this... +1

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for making a very useful Package even in 2021.
However, Polygon output seems to have an error, checked with QGIS 2.18.
I found the error part in **writepolygon[ ]** function for entering Shape Type value(Polygon:5) as follows.

[Original code]

```
writepolygon[stream_, shxstream_, polyrecord_, recordnumber_] := 
 Module[{numpart = Depth@polyrecord[[1]] - 2, numpoints, bounds},
 .... 
  BinaryWrite[
   stream, {3, bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
 ...
```

[Revised code]

```
writepolygon[stream_, shxstream_, polyrecord_, recordnumber_] := 
 Module[{numpart = Depth@polyrecord[[1]] - 2, numpoints, bounds},
 .... 
  BinaryWrite[
   stream, {5, bounds[[1, 1]], bounds[[2, 1]], bounds[[1, 2]], 
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this... I'll update the original answer.