# Strange Error on Fresh Kernel (10.2)

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, warning-messages

**Bug introduced in 10.1**

I wrote a helper function to format real numbers in a certain format for writing .dbf files [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90063/can-mathematica-export-shapefiles). It relies on a new function to 10.1 - `StringPadLeft`.

Here's that function:

```
realformat[num_] := ToString@ScientificForm@PaddedForm[num + 0., {12, 11}, 
 NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", If[ToExpression[(#3 /. "" -> "0")] < 0, "-", "+"], 
 StringPadLeft[StringReplace[ToString@#3, "-" -> ""], 3, "0"]}] &)]

SetAttributes[realformat, Listable]

realformat[{56023.3, 16, -1523532.1}]
```

> `{" 5.60233000000e+004", " 1.60000000000e+001", "-1.52353210000e+006"}`

However, the first time this is called (ie on a fresh kernel), I get the following error:

> `Get::noopen: Cannot open C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\GeneralUtilities-10.2.1\Kernel\ 64.00000000000Bit\GeneralUtilities.mx\`

And the output is as such:

> `{" 5.60233000000e+StringPadLeft[4,  3.00000000000e+StringPadLeft[,  \
>   3.00000000000, 0], 0]", " 1.60000000000e+StringPadLeft[1,  \
>   3.00000000000e+StringPadLeft[,  3.00000000000, 0], 0]", \
>   "-1.52353210000e+StringPadLeft[6,  3.00000000000e+StringPadLeft[,  \
>   3.00000000000, 0], 0]"}`

Oh dear.

Now I can navigate to the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\GeneralUtilities-10.2.1` and manually run the GeneralUtilities package, which solves the issue, but that's rather annoying. All file permissions look okay and I've tried resetting all settings to no avail.

Anybody have a solution or is this a bug?

```
$Version
10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)
```

Comment: For a workaround, evaluate `StringPadLeft;` before running `realformat` which will trigger all necessary autoloading.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to the appropriate developers, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @ilian Thank you much!

Comment: @ilian Can you offer an explanation for the observation I made regarding the conversion of Integer to Real?  I find that quite peculiar.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard While I haven't looked at it in depth, I think what happens is that `PaddedForm` temporarily overrides the default number formatting parameters (and restores them once it is done), but these non-default values are still in effect when the `NumberFormat` option value is applied. For a simpler example, consider   `PaddedForm[1, {2, 3}, NumberFormat -> ((Print@ToString[4]; #1) &)]` where the printed form of 4 is getting padded.

Comment: @ilian Ah!  I never knew of that behavior, but now it makes sense I think.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed by WRI (@ilian) as bug introduced in 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for some reason all Integer values are converted to Real in the environment in which the autoload process takes place, therefore the value of [`$SystemWordLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$SystemWordLength.html) is changed to a Real which breaks the path.  I have been unable to figure out the source of the Integer to Real conversion and therefore I do not know what else it may affect, but I can fix the autoload function itself which at least should handle other cases of this same problem.

```
With[
  {dv := DownValues @ PacletManager`Package`loadWolframLanguageCode},
  dv = dv /. wl : HoldPattern[ToString @ $SystemWordLength] :> RuleCondition[wl];
]
```

Comment: That was the path I started down. But I didn't know if the real number conversion happened only when the message was printed... Then when @ilian stated you can call StringPadLeft first, I abandoned that idea. Interesting, nonetheless.