# Import an binary image with non-standard header

Tags: import, image

I have binary images with an fixed sized header.
These can be converted into PGM images, provided cutting the header, and putting the appropriate information using linux/OSX tools as "head -c", "tail -c", and "cat". I can later import these images in Mathematica for further treatment.

I would like to create an importer in Mathematica [as treated in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html) which could do all this so the import can be done on a Windows station without using the linux/OSX tools.

I have not been able to manage this problem.

The only Idea I had is to use the functions `BinaryReadList` or `BinaryRead`. But since the information I get with them is not the same as what I get with `ImageData[Import[file, "PGM"]]`. I am stuck.

The difference can be directly verified with `binread-module` based an [answer of Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14988/import-fortran-unformatted-binary). And also with a little code I wrote to show the difference on readable files

```
    (* PGM : filename for output *)

    PGM= "/Users/thomas/Documents/Mathematica/LM.pgm";
    Dim = {25,25};
    f[x_,y_]:=2^16*E^(-(2/3) (x^2-0.5` x y+0.25` y^2));

    (* Creating now an small Image *)

    LittleMat=IntegerPart[Array[f,Dim,{{-6,6},{-6,6}}]+1];
    (*LittleMat= RandomInteger[{1,2^16},Dim];*)
    ArrayPlot[LittleMat, ImageSize->{300,300},AspectRatio->Full]

    (* Exporting and re-importing the small Image *)

    Export[PGM,Image[LittleMat,"UnsignedInteger16"],"PGM"];
    ReImp = Import[PGM,"PGM"];
    RI = IntegerPart[2^16*ImageData[ReImp]];

    ArrayPlot[RI, ImageSize->{300,300},AspectRatio->Full]

    (* Information is luckily still the same *)
    (*LittleMat-RI*)

    (* Now reading the file binary, bitwise *)

    Bytestest = FileByteCount[PGM]
    N[Bytestest /(25*25)]

    (* Why is the ImageSize in bits twice the pixel-number? *)

    HeaderL = Bytestest -2*25*25

    stream=OpenRead[PGM,BinaryFormat -> True];
    SetStreamPosition[stream,HeaderL];
    MyPGM = BinaryReadList[stream,"UnsignedInteger16",ByteOrdering->-1];
    SetStreamPosition[stream,0];
    Close[stream];

    (* MyPGM list of the same size as pixel-number *)

    PGMmat = Partition[MyPGM,25];
    ArrayPlot[PGMmat, ImageSize->{300,300},AspectRatio->Full]

    (* Information not the same aby more *)

    ArrayPlot[PGMmat-RI, ImageSize->{300,300},AspectRatio->Full]
```

Comment: just  to answer the easy one "ImageSize in bits twice the pixel - number": the image size in *bytes* is twice the pixel size because you are using 16 bit / 2 byte integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are one byte off when you set stream position, and have the wrong byte ordering.
This makes it work:

```
SetStreamPosition[stream, HeaderL - 1];
MyPGM = BinaryReadList[stream, "UnsignedInteger16", 
   ByteOrdering -> 1];
```

The combined errors happen to make every value < 256 correct, which makes the image look sort-of right.  I think 16 bit PGM is always big endian regardless of your file system.

just by the way you can directly request the integer data from `ImageData` as:

```
RI = ImageData[ReImp, "Bit16"];
```

Comment: Thank you. Even if it looks fine, there is the center pixel which is different, and `PGMmat == RI` gives `False`. Still I would be happy with the result, if the "real life" PGM-Image would work as well, ... I should find a way to send you that small image.

Comment: For the given example : `RI = ImageData[ReImp, "Bit16"];` is much better, since `PGMmat == RI` answers with `True`, but still not for the "real life" PGM-Image. For this image : Even the maximum/minimum are different ...

Comment: the 16 bit range is actually 0-(2^16-1), so you should have had `IntegerPart[(2^16-1)*ImageData[ReImp]]`  You should have `(2^16-1)` in your `f` definition and don't add the `1` after `IntegerPart`  and then it all works out. `RI == PGMmat == LittleMat  (*True*)`

Comment: I will put this question as answered. Maybe the "real life" sample is of different format. I put a [Drop-Box Link to the sample-image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qj67degbdq2hcn/crop2.pgm?dl=0). @george2079 Can you check that? Thnx